# Lighten a fibonacci while loop

Tags: r, fibonacci

This problem has given headache for me and I just can't figure it out. The problem is to write R function which will return every Fibonacci number equal to or less than n.

So far I've tried to make while loop.

```
vast <- function(n) {
 if (n==1) return(1)
 x <- c(1,1)
 while (length(x)-1 < n) {
  pos <- length(x)
  new <- x[pos-1] + x[pos]
  x <- c(x,new)
  }
 x<-x[x <= n]
 return(x)
 }
```

It works like charm except when I try to return the work. At that point the R program starts infinite calculation and the course package jams.

The solution can be also written so that one makes assumption that n is an Fibonacci number. Is there any way to lighten this loop e.g. with break or next statements or would it be easier to approach the problem from different angle?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can't see anything wrong with your function, maybe you can provide an example to elucidate your question. Can can replace `return(x)` with just `x`.

Comment: Similarly, akilu, the function works as advertised for me. Please demonstrate what behavior you're talking about; I suggest showing your code (including input parameters) and the error/warning/message or however you know your R instance is misbehaving.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear info. The problem was that the code was so slow (as Jon Spring stated in his answer) that it jammed the data package used on our course. Replacing `length(x)-1` with `max(x)` made the code lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provides correct output as is, but it's very slow for large numbers. For instance, on my machine, `vast(100000)` (with only 25 elements in the result) takes over 10 seconds to run, and slows down exponentially after that.

The reason it's slow is that your `while` condition is testing if the vector that has `n-1` elements, rather than the bare requirements of a vector whose last / largest vector is `<= n`. For the case of `vast(100000)`, you are creating a 100,000-element vector, when the answer ultimately only needs the first 25 elements.

This code works instantaneously past `n = 10^5000`, whereas the original function gums up in the 100k's on my machine. The only change is that it is now checking to see if the last number in the vector is larger than `n`, not checking if the vector has `n` elements.

```
vast2 <- function(n) {
 if (n==1) return(1)
 x <- c(1,1)
 # while (length(x)-1 < n) {  # OLD
 while (max(x) < n) {        # NEW
  pos <- length(x)
  new <- x[pos-1] + x[pos]
  x <- c(x,new)
  }
 x<-x[x <= n]
 return(x)
 }
```